# web2py scheduling multiple tasks

Tags: python, task, web2py, scheduler

in my web2py app i am using scheduler. So far I have one task scheduled which runs a subprocess when called from controler (an external exe file/application)

Now i want to add another task which will do some background work

My code in **scheduler.py** till now was

def runWoshiEngine(scriptId, path):

```
# import os, sys
# import time
import subprocess
print "runWoshiEngine in progress......"
p = subprocess.Popen(['woshi_engine.exe', scriptId], shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, cwd=path)
return dict(status = 1)


from gluon.scheduler import Scheduler
scheduler = Scheduler(db, heartbeat = 1)
```

so this way the scheduler started on client's request

after starting my app I run my scheduler with command

```
python web2py.py -K myapp
```

Now I want to add another function which will start every hour to do some background work.

What would you recommend and how to add it to scheduler because if i add anything to my line of code my initial task --> exe app is not started

thank you

best regards

Comment: `subprocess`es are not web2py scheduler tasks. Where are you adding tasks to the task_queue?

Comment: IF you mean `def runWoshiEngine(scriptId, path)` this is in scheduler. In another function triggered on user request this subprocess is started